# Permutation with Limiting

Tags: python, permutation, large-data

I want to permute each a set of elements..
However, for each element in the set. I want to limit the times its going to be repeated.

Here is a snip of code to understand:

```
_list_ = [0,1,3]

limit_dict = {
    
    0 : [0, 1],
    1 : [0, 3],
    3 : [0, 1]

}

def main(position=0, length=5, genlist=[]):

    if position == length:
        print (genlist)

    else:

        for element in _list_:

            if limit_dict[element][0] != limit_dict[element][1]:

                limit_dict[element][0] += 1

                main(position + 1, length, genlist + [element])

                limit_dict[element][0] -= 1

main()
```

This is the general idea, is there a faster way to implement this?

I want to do something like this for a large number of integers and therefore cannot use itertools  to achieve this since it uses a lot of memory.

Comment: `itertools` doesn't use a lot of memory.  If you convert the iterator to a list, then of course it's going to use memory, as will ANY solution you come up with.

Comment: No, this solution doesn't, itertools puts all the combinations into a single list at once, where as this solution just works on a single list and prints it out each time

Comment: `itertools` does not put all the combinations into a single list.  It produces an iterator.  It's up to you to decide whether you consume them one by one or convert them to a list.

Comment: OOwwh, wait I just tried itertools, I was putting them into a list the entire time 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `distinct_permutations` [from more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations) does.

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

limit_dict = {
    0 : [0, 1],
    1 : [0, 3],
    3 : [0, 1]
}

elements = (k for k, v in limit_dict.items() for _ in range(*v))
for permutation in distinct_permutations(elements):
    print(permutation)
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, 1, 1, 3)
(0, 1, 1, 3, 1)
(0, 1, 3, 1, 1)
(0, 3, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 0, 1, 3, 1)
(1, 0, 3, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 0, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 0, 3, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 0, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 3, 0)
(1, 1, 3, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 3, 1, 0)
(1, 3, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 3, 1, 0, 1)
(1, 3, 1, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 1, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your solution, but is there a faster approach to accomplish this without using itertools.

Comment: Why? What do you have against itertools?

Comment: Nvm, I just got the solution to the problem, thanks man